# Смысл предложения "баловать жизнью"

Tags: лексика, стилистика, смысл

В одной песни поется:

балую балую балую

самую самую самую

нежной любовью я балую

**жизнью своею я балую**
**(орфография и пунктуация сохранены здесь)**.

Вопрос. Насколько корректно такое предложение и что оно означает? Что-то никак не могу понять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

БАЛОВАТЬ,  нсв. 1. кого. Потворствовать капризам, прихотям, относиться к кому-л. с особой заботой, вниманием, лаской. Б. любимое детище. Б. своих учеников. // **кого (чем). Доставлять удовольствие, радость, делать приятное кому-л**. Б. вниманием, подарками.

Вероятно, здесь такой смысл: посвящать любимой **значительную**  часть своей жизни. Судя по значению слова, те, кого мы балуем,  получают как бы  **избыток** удовольствия, радости, счастья.

Answer (score 1):

В песне некорректно уже потому, что ударение в слове "баловать", "балую" падает на последний слог. А в приведенном отрывке явно - на первый, что противоречит норме.

В отношении же грамматики фраза вполне нормативна. 
Что касается смысла, то у современного песенного текста он часто размыт.

Видимо, автор имел в виду что своим существованием он доставляет удовольствие, потворствует объекту. Хотя, согласен, двусмысленность проскакивает.

Comment: Да, насчет ударения согласен! Грамматически корректна,знаю. Мне показалась стилистически неудачна.

Comment: @Серж Правильно показалась. Стилистически неряшлива. Но песенные тексты, особенно современные, этим вообще страдают. Но я не хочу глубоко копать, много тонких моментов, надо бы сначала убедиться в значении управления "баловать чем".